# How to add a new element to XML data

Tags: xml, perl

I have a requirement to add a new element to some XML data. My input and output is as below.

Here I will give `DINESH` as in input and new element has to be created. The `oid` value has to be incremented by one from the above.

```
<node nspc="DEFAULT" name="CEN509_DINESH" modl="MDL_DINESH" lcmd="node.sh" oid="5" />
```

Thanks for your help

**Input:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root user="gaia" pass="XY6jKWTTBfU=" desc="default user" mail="dinesh@gmail.com">
  <node nspc="DEFAULT" name="CEN509_ASONI" modl="MDL_ASONI" lcmd="node.sh" oid="3" />
  <node nspc="DEFAULT" name="CEN509_ASTI" modl="MDL_ASTI" lcmd="node.sh" oid="4" />
</root>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root user="gaia" pass="XY6jKWTTBfU=" desc="default user" mail="dinesh@gmail.com">
  <node nspc="DEFAULT" name="CEN509_ASONI" modl="MDL_ASONI" lcmd="node.sh" oid="3" />
  <node nspc="DEFAULT" name="CEN509_ASTI" modl="MDL_ASTI" lcmd="node.sh" oid="4" />
  <node nspc="DEFAULT" name="CEN509_DINESH" modl="MDL_DINESH" lcmd="node.sh" oid="5" /> 
</root>
```

Comment: I know I am getting old - but usually it is a bit fuzzy before I put on the specs!

Comment: There is no input and out specified. Please edit your post with input and output.

Comment: Thank you. I thought I was blind!

Comment: What technology should this be implemented in? I notice the question is tagged with java, javascript and perl...

Comment: Is this client side - or server side?

Comment: @user1575765: why did you remove the formatting again. Second, your question is bit too broad (there is not even a question). In most cases  you will use a XML parser to read and manipulate XML files. So, what exactly is your question?

Comment: And why the heck do did you remove my formatting again???

Comment: Sorry all i was new to this.. I need this to be done in any language. But it has to take last line and to create a new line in the below with some change of content

Comment: Use xpath to get the value you want to increment.  Then you have lots of choices to add the new element.

Comment: @user15@: no problem. In general you should ask specific question here at SO. So you should first decide on a language and then do some research how this language can help you in handling XML files. And then, if you're facing some issues come back and we'll be glad to provide further help.

Comment: yes i did some research on perl xml module to achieve this i want to get perl code to do this

Comment: since your question is so broad and the tool/language doesn't seem to matter (which I hardly believe), the easiest way is to copy the line from your question and copy it into your XML-file (using vi, emacs, notepad or whatever tool you want)...

Comment: @user15: Furthermore, this is not a 'plz provide the code' site :-) just google for 'perl xml samples'...

Comment: @pavel: yes we can do this through editor but i want to automate it by giving the value like dinesh...

Comment: @Home: yes i can do that .. But i was totally lost in doing that please help me

Answer (score 2):

This program finds the last `<node>` element, clones it and adjusts the attribute values, and appends it to the parent of the element it was cloned from.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => <<'END', no_blanks => 1);
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root user="gaia" pass="XY6jKWTTBfU=" desc="default user" mail="dinesh@gmail.com">
  <node nspc="DEFAULT" name="CEN509_ASONI" modl="MDL_ASONI" lcmd="node.sh" oid="3" />
  <node nspc="DEFAULT" name="CEN509_ASTI" modl="MDL_ASTI" lcmd="node.sh" oid="4" />
</root>
END


my $input = 'DINESH';

my ($lastnode) = $doc->findnodes('/root/node[last()]');
my $newnode = $lastnode->cloneNode;

my %attr = map { $_ => $newnode->getAttributeNode($_) } qw/ name modl oid /;

my $val;

$val = $attr{name}->getValue;
$val =~ s/[^_]+$/$input/;
$attr{name}->setValue($val);

$val = $attr{modl}->getValue;
$val =~ s/[^_]+$/$input/;
$attr{modl}->setValue($val);

$val = $attr{oid}->getValue;
$attr{oid}->setValue($val + 1);

$lastnode->parentNode->appendChild($newnode);

print $doc->toString(1);
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root user="gaia" pass="XY6jKWTTBfU=" desc="default user" mail="dinesh@gmail.com">
  <node nspc="DEFAULT" name="CEN509_ASONI" modl="MDL_ASONI" lcmd="node.sh" oid="3"/>
  <node nspc="DEFAULT" name="CEN509_ASTI" modl="MDL_ASTI" lcmd="node.sh" oid="4"/>
  <node nspc="DEFAULT" name="CEN509_DINESH" modl="MDL_DINESH" lcmd="node.sh" oid="5"/>
</root>
```